# code coverage 0%

Tags: apex, unit-test, scheduled-apex

I got an error in the inbound change sets in my production mode and found out that my code coverage is 0%.

I created an Apex Class over in a sanbox and I need to get the code coverage to reach 75% but i've been searching and searching and cant seem to get even a percent even after running all test.

What do I do?  Here is my code.  Please advise and thank you in advance

```
public with sharing class ContactSearchController {

    // the soql without the order and limit 
    private String soql {
        get;
        set;
    }
    // the collection of contacts to display
    public List < Contact > contacts {
        get;
        set;
    }

    // the current sort direction. defaults to asc
    public String sortDir {
        get {
            if (sortDir == null) {
                sortDir = 'asc';
            }
            return sortDir;
        }
        set;
    }

    // the current field to sort by. defaults to last name
    public String sortField {
        get {
            if (sortField == null) {
                sortField = 'lastName';
            }
            return sortField;
        }
        set;
    }

    // format the soql for display on the visualforce page
    public String debugSoql {
        get {
            return soql + ' order by ' + sortField + ' ' + sortDir + ' limit 20';
        }
        set;
    }

    // init the controller and display some sample data when the page loads
    public ContactSearchController() {
        soql = 'select firstname, lastname, account.name, interested_technologies__c from contact where account.name != null';
        runQuery();
    }

    // toggles the sorting of query from asc<-->desc
    public void toggleSort() {
        // simply toggle the direction
        sortDir = sortDir.equals('asc') ? 'desc' : 'asc';
        // run the query again
        runQuery();
    }

    // runs the actual query
    public void runQuery() {

        try {
            contacts = Database.query(soql + ' order by ' + sortField + ' ' + sortDir + ' limit 20');
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'Ooops!'));
        }

    }

    // runs the search with parameters passed via Javascript
    public PageReference runSearch() {

        String firstName = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('firstname');
        String lastName = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('lastname');
        String accountName = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('accountName');
        String technology = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('technology');

        soql = 'select firstname, lastname, account.name, interested_technologies__c from contact where account.name != null';
        if (!firstName.equals(''))
            soql += ' and firstname LIKE \'' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(firstName) + '%\'';
        if (!lastName.equals(''))
            soql += ' and lastname LIKE \'' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(lastName) + '%\'';
        if (!accountName.equals(''))
            soql += ' and account.name LIKE \'' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(accountName) + '%\'';
        if (!technology.equals(''))
            soql += ' and interested_technologies__c includes (' + technology + ')';

        // run the query again
        runQuery();

        return null;
    }

    // use apex describe to build the picklist values
    public List < String > technologies {
        get {
            if (technologies == null) {

                technologies = new List < String > ();
                Schema.DescribeFieldResult field = Contact.interested_technologies__c.getDescribe();

                for (Schema.PicklistEntry f: field.getPicklistValues())
                    technologies.add(f.getLabel());

            }
            return technologies;
        }
        set;
    }

}
```

Comment: You need to call the newly created class in your test. Here is a good document to start learning : https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Apex_Code_Test_Methods

Comment: @KingJonathan, I don't see where you've posted the code for your test class. Have I missed something? If you're having trouble writing one, I recommend the following resources: [Visualforce Workbook](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.workbook_vf.meta/workbook_vf/workbook_vf_intro.htm) and [Visualforce Developer’s Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_intro.htm).

Comment: @crmprogdev correct me if im wrong, so i have to add a code that will run the test?

Comment: Can you post you test class so that we can find what the problem is]

Comment: @KingJonathan. That's correct. You need to create another class that runs your test code called a "test class".

Comment: @MarufBagwan I dont have a test class created.  I dont even know where to begin and how to start.  Lol sorry for being a n00b but my only class code is already inserted on top.  The other is just a visualforce page.  

Maybe you guys can help me with a code?
Thanks

Comment: @crmprogdev ill see what i can do but at the moment... im kinda stuck hehe i dont even know where to start lol sorry for being a n00b

Comment: In my comments above, I gave you the link to the VF workbook. It will walk you through examples writing new controllers and the test classes to support them. I also gave you the link to the VF Developer's Guide which will help you as well. Those should give you what you need to help you get started. Should you get stuck, post your code and I'm confident people here will be willing to guide you. If you wrote the code above on your own, you should have little difficulties writing a test class.

Answer (score 4):

During deployment on production, it takes overall test coverage. 
If you are deploying one class and its corresponding test class with code coverage >=75% and still its giving error of code coverage, then it means overall test coverage is below 75%. For that you need check for the classes in production whose code coverage is below 75%. Improve test coverage for those classes and deploy them after increasing code coverage. Issue will be resolved.

Answer (score -1):

I checked the class and it looks ok. Before uploading this class to production, you should run all test in sandbox to see if it works in sandbox.

Comment: it runs in the sandbox that why i went for deployment but it wont accept because the the percentage has to be atlease 75%